# Using object names as parameter names

Tags: javascript, function, object, parameter-passing

In javaScript, I create objects like shown below. When I parse the objects to a function, I normally name the parameter after the object. [See examples below]. My reasoning for this is if another developer comes along and looks at a function they instantly know the function takes a fooObj, a barObj and laaObj. Question is: Is there any syntax/performance issue that could be related to this. (For example, certain browsers that would have a problem with a parameter name being the same name as a object/'function').

```
function exampleObj(name, date, wine, cheese) {
    this.name = name;
    this.date = new Date(date);
    this.wine = wine;
    this.cheese = cheese;

    this.drink = function() {
        open(this.wine);
        pour(this.wine);
        consume(this.wine);
    }

    this.eat = function() {
        unwrap(this.cheese);
        getCrackers();
        informGromitOfCheese(this.cheese);
        consume(this.cheese);

    }
}

var example1 = new exampleObj("Foo", "02/05/2014", "Merlot", "Stinky Bishop");
```

When I pass an object to a function:

```
// Pass the exampleObj here. Param name == Function name
function foo(exampleObj) { // <-- Is this okay?
    alert(exampleObj.name);
}

foo(example1);
```

Comment: @PaulS. I think he wants to know if the parameter name can be the same as any other function. He is actually passing `example1`

Comment: @thefourtheye Yea, my 'objects' are basically functions I store.

Comment: @User2 your username is really cool, btw.

Comment: You can do it as you've shown, but you're shadowing your `exampleObj` constructor, meaning you may not have a reference available to it so can't construct or check with `instanceof` inside `foo` easily.

Comment: @Edward Flattery -> Best way to get a +1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use the same name as the parameter. But we normally use Pascal(Upper Camel Case) to name the classes like `Date`, `Array`.... So you could name the class as `ExampleObj` and instance as `exampleObj` to avoid confused.

Comment: That's the most helpful response so far. Thanks. Will look into Camel Style.

Comment: ...O Goodness! Don't google 'Camel Style' at work. The correct wording is CamelCase. Heres the [WIKI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CamelCase).

Comment: Haha. That's better. The other phrase made me blush at work in-front of my boss. Ahhhh; Friday mornings.

Comment: sorry, it should be Upper Camel Case, it's also called Pascal.

Answer (score 0):

sorry, the answer that i posted before may have been misleading, please have a look at this fiddle and see if you can understand what's going on..

http://jsfiddle.net/h_awk/8W92c/

```
function foo(name, age)
{
    this.name = name;
    this.age = age;

    this.getDetail = function()
    {
        alert('Name is: ' + this.name + ' age is: ' + this.age);
    }
}

function bar(foo)
{
    alert(foo.name);
}

bar(new foo('hawk', '24') );
```

you pass constructor to function bar, then when you call bar, you instantiate foo, it could be done differently.ie.var person = new foo('hawk', 24) and then pass person as a parameter. bar(person) and still get the same result. The this value of foo refers to the function foo hence giving you the expected result, I am sorry and I hope that this helps.. :)

Comment: I got it wrong in my comment before; it's just a name because it's the declaration

Comment: " _because you don't know how different Javascript engines may interpret that_ " - I'd be interested to know that. I've been bitten in the bottom before be javaScript engines acting differently.

Comment: IE and Chrome do not interpret things the same. IE has different keywords such as attachEvent whereas Chrome has addEventHandler. You could do some research on browser compatibilities, I am no expert in Javascript engines. :)